# jQuery min-width vs width: How to remove px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, css

Trying some basic jQuery and JavaScript here.

The `.width()` gives me an integer value.  The `.css('min-width')` gives me a value ending in `px`.  Therefore I can't do math on this as is.  What is the recommended work around?

```
alert($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').width());
alert($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').css('min-width'));
alert($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').width() >= $('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').css('min-width'));

if ($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').width() >= $('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').css('min-width')) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Use `replace()`:

```
alert($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').css('min-width').replace('px', ''));
```

Alternatively, you could use the `parseInt` function:

```
alert(parseInt('1px')); //Result: 1
```

Answer (score 10):

The better way is to use `parseInt`. jQuery functions `.width()` and `.height()` work quite so.

Also, it would be good to encapsulate fetching of this values in standalone functions:

- `.minHeight()`, `.minHeight( size )`, `.minHeight( function() )`
- `.maxHeight()`, `...`
- `.minWidth()`, `...`
- `.maxWidth()`, `...`

Like this:

```
(function($, undefined) {

    var oldPlugins = {};

    $.each([ "min", "max" ], function(_, name) {

        $.each([ "Width", "Height" ], function(_, dimension) {

            var type = name + dimension,
                cssProperty = [name, dimension.toLowerCase()].join('-');

            oldPlugins[ type ] = $.fn[ type ];

            $.fn[ type ] = function(size) {
                var elem = this[0];
                if (!elem) {
                    return !size ? null : this;
                }

                if ($.isFunction(size)) {
                    return this.each(function(i) {
                        var $self = $(this);
                        $self[ type ](size.call(this, i, $self[ type ]()));
                    });
                }

                if (size === undefined) {
                    var orig = $.css(elem, cssProperty),
                        ret = parseFloat(orig);

                    return jQuery.isNaN(ret) ? orig : ret;
                } else {
                    return this.css(cssProperty, typeof size === "string" ? size : size + "px");
                }
            };

        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

And your code will turn to:

```
alert($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').width());
alert($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').minWidth());
alert($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').width() >= $('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').minWidth());
if ($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').width() >= $('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').minWidth()) {
```

Comment: `jQuery.isNaN` should just be `isNaN`. I know this post is old, but this answer is by far the best in here.

Answer (score 2):

Some string manipulation to remove 'px' and then use `parseInt` to get it as a number:

```
var minWidth = parseInt($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').css('min-width').replace('px', ''), 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the return value from `.css('min-width')` to `parseInt` first, it will remove the "px" for you.

```
parseInt(
    $('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').css('min-width'), 
    10
);
```

(Don't forget the second parameter to `parseInt`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('#<%=lstProcessName.ClientID%>').parent('.column4').css('min-width').substring(0,indexOf('px'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substring to the value returning from the min-width to remove the px

Comment: It will still be a string, though.

Comment: but the string a string that is valid to make any operation on it

Comment: what do you want to make with the result ?!

Comment: I just mean that `'50px'.substring(0, 2) + 1 === '501'`.