# how to substract two values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, subtraction

Hi I want to perform a mathematical `subtraction` in jquery.

```
var whm = $(window).height()/2;
var login_height = $("#login").outerHeight();
var login_marign = (whm-login_height);
```

but `login_margin` does not work. How do I subtract the value of these two variables?

Comment: Print `whm` and `login_height` to the console and see if they are numbers. Also, you're written "login_marign" and not "margin"

Comment: What do you man by "not working"? This should work. Are you sure that you are using `login_marign` and not `login_margin`?

Comment: Debug and look at the output from the height() function, as it will have the unit on it (like 'px').  You can remove that and it should work.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917188/jquery-min-width-vs-width-how-to-remove-px

Comment: Are you getting any values in whm and login_height?

Comment: Ohhh...thanks a lot ..that was a typo.sorry:)

Comment: My guess is your typo (ie `login_margin` versus `login_marign`) is fooling you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the issue is derived from a spelling mistake and would not be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do? If you are trying to find the margin around the login (I assume that is the case by looking at your variable name) you can just use the .outerMargin() function.

```
$('#login').outerHeight(true);
```

finds the height of the #login div including content, padding, border, AND margin

```
$('#login').outerHeight();
```

finds the height of the #login div including content, padding, border, but NOT margin

So to find the margin around the element just do

```
var $login = $('#login');
$login.outerHeight(true) - $login.outerHeight();
```

This will return the height of the top and bottom margin, and if they are equal just divide by two to find it's value.

Check it out on http://jsfiddle.net/Prt2J/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Fiddle of it working. I think you spelled margin wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/S88u5/

```
var whm = $(window).height()/2;
var login_height = $("#login").outerHeight();
var login_margin = (whm-login_height);
alert(login_margin);
```